# Cannot perform std with type object Dask

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, datetime-format, dask-dataframe

performing normal calculation on dask is giving me the error

```
x_std = x.std().compute()
```

Computing head:

```py
x.head()

    LocalTime               Ask     Bid
0   2004.10.25 00:01:01.975 86.837  86.877
1   2004.10.25 00:01:19.300 86.791  86.891
2   2004.10.25 00:01:30.759 86.812  86.842
3   2004.10.25 00:01:41.798 86.801  86.831
4   2004.10.25 00:01:42.213 86.794  86.824
```

Error :

```py
TypeError: cannot perform std with type object
```

I was doing in accordance with documentation ...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I formatted the data and error as python code blocks. Check out the [help guide to formatting](/help/formatting) and when asking about errors, please always include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) - it contains lots of valuable debugging information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the output of `x.head()`, it can be seen that one of the columns is a datetime column, however without conversion, it's likely stored as an `object` column. To check dtypes, run:

```py
print(ddf.dtypes)
```

To convert, use `dd.to_datetime` as explained in [this blog post](https://coiled.io/blog/converting-dask-dataframes-object-columns-with-to_datetime/):

```py
from dask.dataframe import to_datetime

# note this overwrites the original column
ddf["LocalTime"] = to_datetime(ddf["LocalTime"])
```

If the other two columns, Ask and Bid, are also objects, then another conversion, to numeric, is needed (see [this blog post](https://coiled.io/blog/dask-dataframe-to-numeric-object-to-float/) for details):

```py
from dask.dataframe import to_numeric

ddf["Ask"] = to_numeric(ddf["Ask"], errors="coerce")
ddf["Bid"] = to_numeric(ddf["Bid"], errors="coerce")
```

After conversion, the `ddf_std = ddf.std().compute()` should work without error.